How to plot dataframe as a table along side a graph?
Hi i have a dataframe called metrics which has 2 rows × 31 columns.
I am plotting a graph using this:
unit_ids = sorting_rec.unit_ids
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sw.plot_unit_templates(we, unit_ids=unit_ids)
plt.suptitle(name, fontsize=12, y=0.01) 
plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.05, 1, 1])
plt.savefig(name+"_xx.png", bbox_inches='tight')

My PI wants me to plot the related dataframe also side by side as a subplot so that it is easy to see the values and the graph both at the same time.
I tried some methods but the output is not something that I desire, the ouput looks like this :


you must create the dataframe and a table to pass the data into it and display it beside the chart:
First, create a dataframe for the table. In this code, I call it summary_df:
summary_df = pd.DataFrame({
'Mean': df.mean(),
'Sum': df.sum()}).T

Then, you must add the table:
table = plt.table(cellText=summary_df.values,
colWidths=[0.2]*len(summary_df.columns),
rowLabels=summary_df.index,
colLabels=summary_df.columns,
cellLoc='center',
rowLoc='center',
loc='bottom')

Finally, you must adjust the program layout to make space for the table. In this code, I prefer to show my table on these axes.
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)

